# How to read ViewBag list in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have a list that I want to pass from my Controller to my View and use JQuery to loop through the list. In my jquery, I can see the ViewBag object but how do I expand the data to actually use it?

My Controller and View are like this:

```
//Controller Index()
var states = GetStatesAvailable();
ViewBag.MyStates = new SelectList(states, "stateID", "Description");
return View();


//View
<script type="text/javascript">
var statesAvailable = "@ViewBag.MyStates";
//Loop through statesAvailable?
</script>
```

Comment: why not try outputting "statesAvailable" and see what you get? Or use C# to serialize the data into JSON before putting it on the viewbag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**MVC CONTROLLER:**

```
   //Controller Index()
    var states = GetStatesAvailable();
    var MyStates = new SelectList(states, "stateID", "Description");
    ViewBag.MyStates = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyStates);
    return View();
```

**JS:**

Just make sure that jQuery is loaded before you run that script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var statesAvailable = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.MyStates);
    //Loop through statesAvailable

    $.each(statesAvailable, function (value)
    {

        console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when I try this, right at the semicolon after var statesAvailable = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.MyStates); in the javascript section.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

try this;

```
var statesAvailable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.MyStates));
```